# How to make join of three tables in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have **three tables** as follows

- user(username address)
- profile(fname,lname,mobile)
- details(performance,activity)

I want **all information** from the above three tables **in one query**

i.e. I want to make **join of three tables** for one common id field

I have the following query which retrives only two table fields

```
 @details=User.find(:all,:joins => :profile,:select => "*")
```

How to do it for all three tables ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how this query would look:

```
@details = User.select('*').joins(:profile, :details).all
```

I'm not convinced this is actually a good way to do anything, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
value_variable = 'hello world'
Member.joins(:person => [:workplace => [:business]]).where("businesses.name LIKE :value", value: "%#{value_variable}%")
```

NOTE: Tested on rails 3.2, 4.x, 5.x